# Connection to Oracle using PHP (odbc_connect) on IIS

Tags: php, oracle, iis, odbc

I am trying to connect to an Oracle database using the odb_connect() function in PHP. PHP is installed on IIS.

I am using the following command :

```
 $dsn="Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};Server=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=******)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=***)));Uid=***;Pwd=***";
 $connect = odbc_connect($dsn, '****', '***') ;
```

Unfortunately why the script is run I get the following error :

> Warning: odbc_connect(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC driver for Oracle][Oracle], SQL state NA000 in SQLConnect in ..

Any ideas on why this is happening would be gratly appreciated. I have tried to look online for a solution but since i've never done this before I havn't managed to fix it.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Try this : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/264012 Also you may post more info (IIS Version, OS, MDAC, PHP version, Oracle DB version, etc...)

Comment: PHP Version 5.3.14 /  Windows XP SP3 / IIS 5.1 . I am not sure however how to get the MDAC and Oracle DB version. I do not have direct access to the instance where the DB is installed. I've tried installing MDAC_TYP.exe but i get "this setup does not support installing on this system" and i'm also not sure which of the .reg files i should run from the orareg.exe archive.